# SystemC - building but not running

Tags: c++, hdl, systemc

I have recently started learning systemC and have got a problem simulating the FIFO module I have written. The code actually compiles without any error/warning but when I run the simulation, I don't get the expected output. I have uploaded the code in [this link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6BPH).

For debugging, in the top level, before `sc_start();` I have written the following line to make sure simulation is running up to that point

```
std::cout<< "Top:Simulation Started" <<std::endl;
```

In the tb.cpp file I have a process named "source" and the first line of the process is

```
std::cout<< "Source:Simulation Started" <<std::endl;
```

In the output of the simulation, I see only first cout, i.e. "Top:Simulation Started" but the other cout doesn't appear.

I am now puzzled and don't know how to handle this problem as I don't get any error.
I would appreciate if someone could advise me what the problem can be

Thanks